# Some images not displayed in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-365

I'm displaying images in my SSRS Report. Some images displayed in report and some not. Some png, jpeg images displaying but some jpeg not dispaying and no error messages. How to check the image format? Is there any restriction for image formats in SSRS?  Note: It is SSRS Report in Dynamics 365 Online, so I could not check SSRS error logs.

update: Looks like the image size matters. The same file, If I resize and make it smaller size then it is displayed in the report. In my case the image size is 1.8 MB, when I resized it to 30 KB, then it is displayed in the report.

Comment: When adding the image file to the report, Windows Explorer will show the file format. You can also look at the filename extension.

Comment: I have verified the filename extension, even I have checked the image file with some metadata tools, all shows it has the meme type as "image/jpeg". But still it is not showing in the report. I just want to know where I can check the error details and how to troubleshoot this with the "Dynamics CRM 365 Online SSRS environment".

Comment: Did you at all add the Images to the report? Please clarify how the image data is accessed. It seems to me that you are trying to link external Images via http instead of embedding the Image files into the rdl. Also: If you can't error logs checked (by yourself or by your cloud application provider) for a product that you are paying for, chose another product or another provider.